# Query must begin with SELECT or WITH error?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I tried to execute the plsql `IF` statement based on the condition. But it does not work.

```
declare
  admin varchar2(4000);
  user1 varchar2(4000);

begin
  Admin := q'~
             SELECT *  INTO ADMIN FROM CI_PREFERENCE ;
             ~';    
  User1 :='~
             SELECT * FROM CI_PREFERENCE  WHERE EMAIL_ID = lower(:APP_USER);
           ~';
  if :G_ADMIN = 'A' then
    return admin;
  else
    return user1;
  end if;
end;
```

It Shows:

> ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH error

Comment: Error seems like it is oracle and you have tag plsql?

Comment: Your string in `User1` will begin with ~ as you've missed the q to define the quote characters.

Comment: That error cannot possibly have been returned by that anonymous block. You'd get either `ORA-01008: not all variables bound` or `PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression`, depending on whether you pass a bind variable in or not. Please update your sample code so that it demonstrates the actual issue.

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` tag, as this is clear Oracle

Comment: Another issue could be that your second select has no into clause

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is missing the `Q` for the alternative quoting syntax.  Replace

```
User1 :='~
             SELECT * FROM CI_PREFERENCE  WHERE EMAIL_ID = lower(:APP_USER);
           ~';
```

with

```
User1 := q'~
             SELECT * FROM CI_PREFERENCE  WHERE EMAIL_ID = lower(:APP_USER);
           ~';
```

Comment: are you sure that this will work?

Comment: @hotfix It was hard to see the difference, but the original code was missing the `q` that made the alternative quoting mechanism work.  I updated the answer to hopefully make it more obvious.

Comment: @JonHeller, 

that could be the cause of the error. However, the Select statement is also not quite correct because it there no into clause

Comment: @hotfix I *think* what's going on here is that the PL/SQL block is returning a query, and that query is being executed by some other process.  For example, that style is used in Oracle APEX.  That kind of process would better explain the error message.  But we're all just making poor guesses here unless the OP edits the question and adds more details.